# If row contains specified value then copy ID to first column

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

If a row contains the value "car" I am trying to copy the contents of the ID cell to A1.

For example, if row D12 contains "car" I want to copy the contents of cell B12 to A12.

Currently this is my code:

```
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim cell As Range

lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

For Each cell In Range("D2:D" & lastRow)
If InStr(1, cell.Value, "CAR") <> 0 Then
            cell.Offset(0, -3).Value = "test"
    End If
Next
```

So currently the code find's the rows that has "car" but populates the cell with the value "test". I am struggling with how to reference/copy the cell over.

This is because the first column of my worksheet requires a concatenation of values as the ID and I do not want to apply it to this string.

Thanks for any advice/help!

Comment: change the word "test" to `cell.Offset(0, -2).Value`.  You need to tell the code what you want A to be.  Right now it is being told "test".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get "test" as inserted in to column A is, that is what the code is specifying.  The code needs to be changed to reflect what is wanted.

If the contents of column B is wanted, then replace the string "test" with:

```
cell.Offset(0, -2).Value
```

So the whole line would read:

```
cell.Offset(0, -3).Value = cell.Offset(0, -2).Value
```

Since you are iterating through column D, `cell` is located in column D.  The offset part is saying, "Move over three places from column D and place the value from two columns over".  Or column A on the same row, which is 3 cells to the left from the current cell in column D and place the value from Column B on the same row, which is 2 cells to the left of the current cell in column D.

Answer (score 1):

Another quick way would be to use the autifilter.
For example:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
    lastRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Columns("D:D").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*Car*"

    Set rng1 = Range("A2:A" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Set rng2 = Range("B2:B" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    rng1.Value = rng2.Value

    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = 0

End Sub
```

Comment: First you tell me to answer, then steal my thunder.  I thought we were friends :P